# How to connect two sensors into Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, sensors, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to use Raspberry Pi 2 to connect two sensors and let them work.
They are a DFROBOT analog light sensor and a DFROBOT analog sound sensor.

I am also using a AD converter, and the converter connect to SCL and SDA pins on Raspberry Pi.

The converter has four Ains, so I can use two of them, one connect to light sensor, one connect to sound sensor.

Could somebody help me with the Python code? 
I want to let my Pi receive 1 second for Ain1(Light sensor) and 1 second for Ain2(Sound sensor), alternately.

Here is my code, but It seems that it doesn't work well.

```
import time

import datetime

from smbus import SMBus

bus = SMBus(1)

def readSoundSensor():

    return bus.read_byte(0x48)

def runSoundSensor():

    bus.write_byte(0x48,0x00)
    last_reading = -1
    sound = readSoundSensor()
    timestamp= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    record = str(timestamp) + ":" +str(sound)
    print "Sound: "+record

def readLightSensor():

    return bus.read_byte(0x48)

def runLightSensor():

    bus.write_byte(0x48,0x01)
    last_reading = -1
    light = readLightSensor()
    timestamp= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    record = str(timestamp) + ":" +str(light)
    print "Light: "+record

while(Ture):

   runSoundSensor()

   time.sleep(1)

   runLightSensor()

   time.sleep(1)
```

My Pi has some data, but I data is not what I want, and is not as when I connect just a single sound/light sensor.

I am totally new in Raspberry Pi, and I don't know anything about address 0x48, etc, I just learn from some guide. Could someone help me where I was wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `while(Ture):` is obviously wrong.

You are writing the same command - `0x48 0x00` to the A/D for both the sensors - that can't be correct, unless it samples all inputs on each read?

Are you sure you have the correct SMBUS address - `0x48`?
What is this command `0x00` meant to do?

To clarify, SMBUS commands will consist of `address in hex, command byte(s) in hex`. You might want to read up on SMBUS / I2C addressing: [This](http://www.totalphase.com/support/articles/200349176-7-bit-8-bit-and-10-bit-I2C-Slave-Addressing) article is quite good.

I would imagine that at the very least you need to send a command to select one of the `Ain` inputs and then another to sample it. `0x00` looks more like a reset.

Have you read the documentation for the A/D?

Comment: Thanks for your replaying!
I don't quiet know what's the meaning of 0x48,0x00, I guess 0x48 is the SDA/SCL pins address in Raspberry Pi? and 0x00 is the Ain0 for the A/D?

What if I change the second 0x00 to 0x01? may that help?
I will read the documentation haha, thanks for your advice.

Comment: `0x48` is the slave address that you are writing to / reading from. It is a property of the slave device, in your case, the A/D. `0x00` is the command byte, which you write to, or the register you read from.